# Do I need transit visa if I have to recheck my checked-in baggage for a layover in Dubai?

Tags: visas, transit, luggage, indian-citizens, dxb

I am buying ticket for Delhi from Kiev with layover at Dubai.  On the ticket it is written

> Recheck of checked luggage needed.

Airline is from kiev - Ukranian international airline to Dubai then Spice jet from Dubai till Delhi.

Comment: Is this Dubai International Airport DXB?

Comment: Yes, it is DXB Dubai international airport)

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: I am Indian by nationality.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to re-check your luggage upon landing at DXB then you'll need a visa to enter Dubai. Luckily this is a somewhat easy procedure for Indian citizens. You can either transit without visa, or request a 96-hour transit visa on arrival. Quoting from [the Emirates website](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/find_visa_requirements/visa_passport_information_results.aspx?NC=IN&NV=India&DC=IN&DV=India&TC=AE&TV=United+Arab+Emirates&h=568d7e709337e5e7ad136f5056707a5a59026):

> ### Transit - United Arab Emirates (AE)
>
> #### Visa
>
> Visa required.
>
> #### TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> Holders of confirmed onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours.
>   Visa is required for transit between Dubai International Airport (DXB) and Dubai Al Maktoum International (DWC).
>
> #### Visa Issuance:
>
> A 96-hour transit visa can be obtained on arrival at Dubai (DXB), provided:
>
> - transit time is at least 8 hours; and
> - holding onward ticket to a third country; and
> - holding a passport valid for at least 6 months from date of arrival.
>     Visas are only issued as a part of a transit package together with hotel accommodation and airport transfer (paid by passenger).

If unsure what to do once you land, locate the transfer desks B and C and ask them. [The DXB aiport webpage has more information on connecting flights.](http://www.dubaiairports.ae/before-you-fly/procedures/flight-connections)