# Will my luggage be transferred automatically on a layover between T3 and T2 of Dubai International?

Tags: luggage, layovers, dxb, jet-airways

I am arriving at T3 of Dubai DXB from Jet Airways and having an onward flight to Kiev Boryspil KBP with Ukrainian Airlines from T2. Flight departure time is 09:20 hours and I have bought a single ticket.

What is the procedure of transferring my luggage between the terminal? Do I have to do recheck-in in the Dubai airport with all my luggage?

Comment: And when do you arrive at t3? Is the Kiev flight on a different airline? Did you buy a single ticket or do you have 2 tickets?

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/89051/edit) explaining which airport you are talking about. If not it will be impossible to answer it. :)

Comment: Yes it is dubai international airport

Comment: What does your ticket say? [See this related question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66817/do-i-need-transit-visa-if-i-have-to-recheck-my-checked-in-baggage-for-a-layover/66881#66881) for more info.

Comment: Ticket is just saying that i have to transfer for t3 to t2 and it donot state anything that i hv to shift my luggage by myself or airline will do it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need transit visa if I have to recheck my checked-in baggage for a layover in Dubai?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66817/do-i-need-transit-visa-if-i-have-to-recheck-my-checked-in-baggage-for-a-layover)

Comment: Given that Ukraine International airlines [is not a through check-in partner](http://www.jetairways.com/EN/MU/jetexperience/through-check-in-partners.aspx) of Jet Airways it seems to me that you would have to re-check-in. Who sold you the ticket?

Answer (score 3):

As you haven't returned to clarify your flight arrangements, there are several possibilities. The simplest: your bags will be checked through and you just have to get to your connecting flight.

If your luggage is not checked through, then you will have to collect it and, to do that, you may a visa, as the baggage carousels are after the immigration counters.

You should certainly find this out in advance, as you need to determine whether you are able to get a visa on arrival, or need to get a transit visa in advance of your departure.

Take a look at the excellent [description by @BurhanKhalid on navigating your way through the Dubai airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/82625/how-to-figure-out-my-departure-gate-at-dubai-airport-terminal-3/83204#83204), going from Terminal 3 to Terminal 2.

Answer (score 1):

> I am arriving at T3 of Dubai DXB from Jet Airways and having an onward
>   flight to Kiev Boryspil KBP with Ukrainian Airlines from T2. Flight
>   departure time is 09:20 hours and I have bought a single ticket.

Terminal 3 is for Qantas and Emirates only. Jet Airways flights arrive at Terminal 1.

"Ukrainian Airlines" - I think you mean "Ukraine International Airlines" which also uses Terminal 1.

Now, since both your airlines are using Terminal 1, you don't need to worry about transferring terminals.

If you are on one ticket for the entire journey, then your luggage will be transferred.

If you have two separate **tickets** then you'll need to enter Dubai (which means, you'll need a visa), collect your luggage, and then check in again.

It also means you cannot board your Jet Airways flight unless you are able to land and enter in Dubai.